# What is the difference between efficiency and efficacy?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between the above words? Are they interchangable? I have seen several instances where *efficacy* has been used where it seems that *efficiency* is the correct term. Please forgive me if this question has been asked elsewhere. If anyone could point me in the direction of an explanation I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please read the question which was closed as general reference. [Is there any difference in meaning between 'efficacy' and 'efficiency'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50662/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-efficacy-and-efficiency).

Comment: Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Would you like me to delete this question? Apologies for any rule-breaking.

Comment: It is up to you. You didn't break any rule as you were not aware of it. Please try to read the guidelines of our Help Center. You need to show us some research efforts on the two words and tell us what you understand and what you don't. That will make your question on-topic. Good luck.

Comment: I'd usually say it's a *good* idea not to delete questions closed as duplicates, because the fact of there being different titles (and other indexed text) might help future posters find a duplicate before asking *again*. In this case I don't think that's a significant factor, but I still see no reason to delete the later question.